# MySql select and update and return the updated ids (in atomic way)

Tags: mysql, sql

in MySql 8 i need to execute some sql statement in atomic way.

1)I have to select rows that matches the condition (limit to 10)

```
SELECT Id from Table1 where Reserved is false LIMIT 10
```

2)I need to update the selected rows setting the column Reserved to True:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET Reserved = true Where ....
```

I have to return the updated rows ids to client.

How can i do?

Thanks

Comment: And explain the relationship between adsprofile and table1

Comment: SELECT and UPDATE can be combined into one query formally, but due to updated rows ids to be returned they must be separate. Final non-listed but described SELECT must be separate. So stored procedure needed. Due to a rowset to be returned temporary table must be used.

Comment: Learn about transactions.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your table1 is not the same as AdsProfile and the table1 table are not influenced  by uthe update for AdsProfile

You could try

using an upodate wuith join on a subquery

```
UPDATE AdsProfile  a 
inner join  (
  SELECT Id from Table1 where Reserved is false LIMIT 10

) t on t.id = a.id
SET a.Reserved = true
```

and for the updated  row should be

```
select id from table1 t1
inner join (
SELECT Id 
from Table1 where Reserved is false LIMIT 10
) t2 on t2 id= t1.id
inner join ( 
select id from  AdsProfile  a 
  inner join  (
    SELECT Id from Table1 where Reserved is false LIMIT 10

  ) t on t.id = a.id
  where a.revered = true
) t3.t3.id = t1.id
```

Comment: Nothing guarantees that `id` values returned by 2nd query are those which were updated by 1st query.. none query contains ORDER BY even!

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_name ()
BEGIN
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_table_name;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_table_name
    SELECT Id FROM Table1 WHERE Reserved IS FALSE LIMIT 10;
UPDATE AdsProfile JOIN tmp_table_name ON ...
    SET Reserved = true 
    Where ....;
SELECT * FROM tmp_table_name;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_table_name;
END
```

On the client side execute the next SQL statement:

```
CALL sp_name;
```